# Accessing String key to display fetch image (Swift)

Tags: swift, dictionary

I am trying to correspond the "major" from my dictionary to a picture associated with each major so it displays in the cell.

```
import Foundation

class ClassRosterModel {
    var studentsRoster = [Dictionary<String, String>] ()
    init () {
        studentsRoster.append(["name": "Kaz, Alex", "number" : "s0834347", "major" : "SE"])
        studentsRoster.append(["name": "O'Rore, Ryan", "number" : "s0835357", "major" : "SE"])
        studentsRoster.append(["name": "Lote, Lote", "number" : "s0835357", "major" : "SE"])
        studentsRoster.append(["name": "Flora, Nico", "number" : "s0748324", "major" : "MA"])
    }
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)

    // Configure the cell...
    cell.textLabel?.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["name"]
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = studentsList[indexPath.row]["number"]
    print("Student's name: \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["name"])")
    print("Student's number: \(studentsList[indexPath.row]["number"])")

    return cell
```

Comment: It's unclear what your issue is. Please update your question.

Comment: So what's the issue?

Comment: I wouldn't use an array of dictionaries, you should just use a struct. But anyway, that should work, you already added "major"

Comment: okay i reworded the question, I am trying to access one of three pictures for lets say SE, CS, or MA for the cell on the table view.

Comment: Please add both what you expect to happen, and what is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a dictionary to map from your "major" to the image, for example:

```
let images = [
    "SE": UIImage(named: "se-image.png"),
    "MD": UIImage(named: "another-image.png")
]
let major = studentsList[indexPath.row]["major"]
if let image = images[major] {
    cell.imageView?.image = image
}
```

---

I'm gonna be nice to you, and provide you with a better example of how to write good Swift code:

```
enum Major: String {
    case SE
    case MA

    var image: UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: self.rawValue)
    }
}
struct Student {
    let name: String
    let number: String
    let major: Major
}

class SomeTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let students = [
        Student(name: "Kaz, Alex",    number: "s0834347", major: .SE),
        Student(name: "O'Rore, Ryan", number: "s0835357", major: .SE),
        Student(name: "Lote, Lote",   number: "s0835357", major: .SE),
        Student(name: "Flora, Nico",  number: "s0748324", major: .MA)
    ]

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let student = students[indexPath.row]

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("studentCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel?.text = student.name
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = student.number
        cell.imageView?.image = student.major.image
        return cell
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks that was the problem. the storyboard isn't allowing me to add an image from the library to my subtle cell for some reason so I'm trying to tackle that now.

Comment: I added a code example so you can make your app better, please study it. :)

Answer (score 0):

In your code you've declared `var studentsRoster = [Dictionary<String, String>] ()` which means an array of dictionaries which contain keys & values of strings. The first thing you'll probably want to do is fix that if you did not intent for it to be an array of dictionaries.

Basically, `[String]` is shorthand for an array of strings. `Array<String>` is the long form. Likewise, `Dictionary<String, String>` is the long form of declaring a dictionary and you can use the shorthand of `[String:String]`

So the code you need to start with is more than likely `var studentsRoster = [String:String]()`

You can add a new key and set it's value with `studentsRoster["key"] = "Value"`

It would do you a lot of good to read the following: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH8-ID113